# Why is my button not fully lining up?

Tags: html, css, image

I've got a button posted here:

http://buttontest.raptorshop.com/

But for some reason, it isn't entirely lining up. What can cause this?

I tried changing line height, padding, etc.

Here's the CSS code I have:

```
a.gbutton {
    background: transparent url('buttonside.png') no-repeat scroll top right;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
    height: 82px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 46px; /* sliding doors padding */
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.gbutton span {
    background: transparent url('buttonmain.png') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    line-height: 68px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
}
```

I am modifying this from a tutorial I found online, and perfect CSS placement has always been a difficult item for me.

Comment: What is your expected position for the button?

Comment: Eventually I plan on putting them in the middle of the page, inside a CMS.

Comment: Why don't you make the whole ellipse as a single image?

Comment: Because the text size will change and I want the button to be able to change in size.

Comment: How is using two images different?

Comment: Supposedly it will use the "sliding door technique" here - allowing the images to resize to fit the text:

http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html

Comment: For sliding door to work, the rest of the image except the edges has to have parallel sides, so that extending them wont change shape. You have a ellipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sliding door technique works because extending a rectangle won't change its look. But extending a ellipse will, so your code won't work as you expect.

Here is the best I could get:

```
a.gbutton {
    background: transparent url('buttonside.png') no-repeat scroll right top;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
    height: 82px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 51px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.gbutton span {
    background: transparent url('buttonmain.png') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    display: block;
    line-height: 68px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Update**

Just use a single image and specify the CSS:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Comment: So you think I should just replace my double images with one image then?